# How can I import function based indexes using impdp?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp

I have a number of tables that use function based indexes (indices if you prefer). These indexes use functions within packages that I have defined. When importing the schema of the user it would appear that the tables get imported first, then the indexes and then the packages.

I say thin because I get errors such as the following;

```
ORA-39083: Object type INDEX failed to create with error:
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "DEVELOPE.METAPHONE" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "DEVELOPE.METAPHONE"
Failing sql is:
CREATE INDEX "DEVELOPE"."CLAIMS_PATIENT_INDEX_2" ON "DEVELOPE"."CLAIMS_PATIENT" (
"GENDER", "DEVELOPE"."METAPHONE"."GENPRIMKEY"("NAME_FIRSTNAME",3), 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("DOB",'YYYY')), SUBSTR("ADDR_ZIP",1,3)) PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 
MAXTRANS 166  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTEN
```

Are there parameters within impdp that will resolve this problem? Or another workaround?

If I create the index after the impdp finishes, everything works fine.

Comment: This is "Bug 17943479  ORA-39083/ORA-904 from Import with REMAP_SCHEMA for virtual column or function based index on PLSQL function".  The workaround is "none".  The bug claims to be fixed in 12.2 but I just hit the same problem in that version.  It's pretty annoying to hit the same problem 5 years later and there's still no simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option: `content=data_only` or you can write your own importer by using [DATAPUMP API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL600)

You can import your schema with several attempts:

1. tables and tables' data
2. functions
3. indexes

I believe it has to be possible to implement.

Comment: content=data_only will import the row data, how do I then create the packages and indexes?

Comment: I looked at the DATAPUMP API link briefly. I did not see a way (did I mention briefly) to change the order that the import does things. Did I miss it?

Comment: You can import your schema with several attempts: at first tables and tables' data then functions and at the end indexes. I believe it has to be possible to implement.

Comment: I agree with zaratustra that running in multiple passes is likely the best solution.  I've had to do that before to avoid similar issues with indexes and datapump.